# Odd artifacting problem only in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

This has been happening pretty consistently in the past 24 hours, it seems any time intellisense comes up visual studio gets these black garbled rectangles all over it. I thought this was a video card issue so I swapped it out for a new one, and the issue persisted. Has anybody seen this problem before? Sorry if this isn't exactly code related.

[image: visual studio problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is enabled, you can try turning off Hardware Acceleration in Visual Studio under Tools > Options. Make sure to check "Show All Settings" as well.

[image: Visual Studio Dialog]